# CoreData Threading. iOS 6 vs 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I'm having an issue related to my core data implementation and threading. It works fine on iOS 7 but I can't get the main context to refresh properly on iOS 6.

I have two NSPersistentStoreCoordinators pointing to the same database file. I then have a main context and a background context. All new child contexts are children of the background context.

When I update items on child contexts in background threads on 6 they never merge to the main context until I restart the app and the main context fetches them from the store. On ios7 this all works fine however. How can I ensure the main context is refreshing the merge properly without faulting and reloading the db?

I know iOS 7 turned on asynchrounous sql access by default, but I've done that on 6 with:

```
  NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{@"journal_mode" : @"WAL"}
```

Here is how my context's are set up:

```
    self.mainManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [self.mainManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.mainPersistentStoreCoordinator];
    [self.mainManagedObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy];
    [self.mainManagedObjectContext setUndoManager:nil];
    self.backgroundParentContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [self.backgroundParentContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.backgroundPersistentStoreCoordinator];
    [self.backgroundParentContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy];
    [self.backgroundParentContext setUndoManager:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(backgroundContextDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:self.backgroundParentContext];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mainContextDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:self.mainManagedObjectContext];
```

Here is how I create a child context:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)newChildManagedObjectContext
{
     NSManagedObjectContext *childContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] 
                                 initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

     [childContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];

     [childContext setParentContext:self.backgroundParentContext];

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(managedObjectContextDidSave:)
                                name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:childContext];
     [childContext setUndoManager:nil];
     return childContext;
}
```

Here are the notification methods:

```
- (void)mainContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    __block NSNotification *strongNotification = notification;
    [self.backgroundParentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    [self.backgroundParentContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:strongNotification];
    }];
 }

 - (void)backgroundContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
 {
    [self.mainManagedObjectContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:NO];
 }

 - (void)managedObjectContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
 {
      [self.backgroundParentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
      NSError *error = nil;
      if (![self.backgroundParentContext save:&error]) {
             DNSLog(@"error saving context: %@", error); 
       }
   }];
 }
```

UPDATE:

Well it appears this is just never going to work on 6. According the docs, they have changed quite a bit around merging contexts for 7. So I'm going to have to take a different approach for 6 I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been using two `NSPersistentStoreCoordinators` on iOS 6, but merging changes between contexts from different store coordinators was mentioned explicitly during WWDC, so I think it's changed in iOS 7. See the following sessions:

- 207 - ￼What’s New in Core Data (starting from slide number 145).
- 211 - Core Data Performance (starting from slide number 91),